# Can I call function on each segment of a d3 pie chart?

Tags: d3.js

In d3 charts, let's say pie chart. Is it possible to write function for each pie segment?

Example: If I have a pie chart and the two pie segments are "high" and "low". Can I write a function for when user clicks on the "high" segment particular event should happen or particular page it should be navigated to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(This is "too broad" for SO. Still, here is an answer)*

When you click on the `path` element you can retrieve the bound data (as when you click on any element with data bound) using the first argument:

```
path.on("click", function(d){
    //code based on d, such as:
    //if(d.foo == bar){ do something }
}
```

Based on the data, you can set the function you want. For instance, in this demo, the two slices have a name, "high" and "low". Clicking on any of them alerts its respective name:

```js
var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);
  
var data = [{slice: "high", value: 40},
{slice: "low", value: 5},]

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 80)
    .innerRadius(radius - 80);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  var slice = g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.slice); });
   
   var texts = g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.slice; });
   
   slice.on("click", function(d){
   alert("This is the " + d.data.slice + " slice");
   })
```

```css
.arc text {
  font: 14px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```